# Inherited application

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I just inherited a WinForm application. Part of the code seems too similar. For each control type, is executing the same, just casting. For instance:

```
    private void oSelectedControl_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (oSelectedControl.Type == "Advance")
        {
            oProperties.SelectedObject = ((Advance)oSelectedControl.SelectedControl).Properties;
        }
        else if (oSelectedControl.Type == "PercentageGauge")
        {
            oProperties.SelectedObject = ((PercentageGauge)oSelectedControl.SelectedControl).Properties;
        }
        else if (oSelectedControl.Type == "TrevoMeter")
        {
            oProperties.SelectedObject = ((TrevoMeter)oSelectedControl.SelectedControl).Properties;
        }
        .
        .
        .
  }
```

And it continues for at least 40 controls.

Is there any way to do it with generics or so?

Thanks

Comment: Generics won't help. But, given a lack of a common base type defining the required property I would be tempted to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using inheritance by having each of the controls inherit a abstract base class containing this particular property.

```
abstract class ControlBase 
{
   abstract object Properties { get; }
}
```

Comment: It does not need to be a abstract class, a interface would be more appropriate in this situation IMHO due to the fact that the base class is not implementing any logic.